# IIS Application Pool creating folder with applicationhost.config in it

Tags: iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012, applicationhost

This one has me baffled. Everytime we create an application pool on a newly built server it and run it, it creates a folder in the root of IIS. Such as all our default IIS folders are configured at parent to be D:\IIS and each time a pool starts, it creates D:\IIS\POOLNAME. This folder contains the same permissions structure as the INETSRV folder and contains an applicationhost.config named as the application pool.

Some sort of wacky debugging? Anyone seen this before?

Comment: IIS itself does create a cached config file for each running pools, under %systemdrive%\inetpub\temp\appPools\ If you moved the default folders, then such files would be at another location. Super natural.

Comment: ok, but where is this config set?

Comment: Leave it alone. You are not supposed to touch it.